# Java synchronization - waiting for data from server

Tags: java, synchronization, client-server

I have a classic server / client problem where a class is waiting for a data update from a server at regular intervals. In a nutshell my program is as follows:

```
public synchronized void eodProcess() {
    //DO STUFF
    dataReady = false;
    while (!dataReady) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
  //DO STUFF
  }

public void update(){
    //CODE THAT DOWNLOADS FROM SERVER
    synchronized(this){
        dataReady = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Both eodProcess() and update() are scheduled to run at the same time every evening.

Now the code above has always worked as the data download takes a few seconds, but it seems like the wrong way of doing things, as in theory update() could run faster than eodProcess(), set dataReady to true, then eodProcess would set it to False and then wait forever. What would be the correct way of making sure eodProcess waits for the data to be ready?

I was thinking about scheduling a new process that would set dataReady to false a few minutes before either of the two methods and removing the initialization at the beginning of eodProcess, but that doesn't seem very clean.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you mean threads when talking about processes.

Comment: Who decides what needs to be downloaded? It looks like it might be a good idea to encapsulate that to-be-downloaded work into a Callable, then submit it to an ExecutorService to get back a Future. Then, `future.get()` blocks until the download is complete (you'd call that from eodProcess, possibly). But there are other models that could also work, like a BlockingQueue or possibly even single-threading the whole thing. This problem doesn't give us enough info to recommend one answer over another, so it's probably too broad for SO.

Comment: @yshavit, thank you - I'm looking at ExecutorService and that seems like it would work too. Single-threading wouldn't work without significant rewriting of existing code. Same data is downloaded every day through a scheduler (get daily data from database, clean it up...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic situation when application of `CountDownLatch` is useful.

```
CountDownLatch downloadDone = new CountDownLatch(1);

[...]

public synchronized void eodProcess() {
    //DO STUFF

    downloadDone.await();
  //DO STUFF
  }

public void update(){
    //CODE THAT DOWNLOADS FROM SERVER
    downloadDone.countDown();
}
```

It's basically a semaphore, but nicer. Await will only proceed when the latch counts down to zero (or the thread is interrupted). If you need the ability to reset the count, consider using `CyclicBarrier` (it works about the same, but there's a `reset` method)

Comment: Thank you - can I then also remove the synchronized from eodProcess?

Comment: @alex314159: Yup. The latch handles synchronization problems on its own.

Comment: Right - this should do the trick, thanks for introducing me to that class. Can I just reset the count (and getting ready for the next day) by recreating the latch at the end of eodProcess?

Comment: @alex314159: yes, although a `CyclicBarrier` might be more suitable (but for case like that it doesn't really matter as long as you can guarantee that the reassignment is seen by both threads).